# WFS filter on entire row?

Tags: postgis, geoserver, wfs, cql-filter, cql

With PostgreSQL I can query an entire row for a string:

`SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE table_name::text LIKE '%string%';`

Is there an equivalent (CQL?) for a Geoserver WFS serving PostGIS data?

I've had a look [here](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/cql/cql_tutorial.html) and [here](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/function_reference.html#filter-function-reference) but found nothing.

Answer (score 2):

It is on https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/cql/cql_tutorial.html

Like function (implemented on org.geotools.filter.LikeFilterImpl Geotools class) is used as following example:

```
field LIKE '%pattern%'
```

Now for the entire row (all columns) concatenation you could use the concatenate function:

```
concatenate(field1,field2)
```

Finally I recommend you to use a computed Text field saved with a trigger (INSERT, UPDATE) storing all text data you need and use this new field on your LIKE conditions.

Comment: I think my question might have been poorly expressed :) I am fully aware of `field LIKE '%pattern%'`. I also do not need to have a computed Text field saved with a trigger, PostgGreSQL already has this feature, and `... WHERE table_name::text LIKE ...` is how one uses it. Concatenate sounds interesting, you're suggesting to do `... WHERE concatenate(fieldX, fieldY, fieldZ) LIKE '%pattern%'`?